# set irregular alarms daily using alarmManager

Tags: android, alarm

I want to set notifications/alarms everyday at specific times. Please note that these times could be different for everyday. For example I have a Database from which I get 5 different entries/times for a day e.g 6am, 1.30pm, 4.30pm, 7.30pm, 10.00 pm. I want to set an alarm for these times. For the next day these times could be different. They could be off by 2-5 minutes or more. 
Basically I cannot set a recurring alarm for the same time everyday. I need to check the entry in my Database to know what time I should schedule it.

What is a good and efficient way of doing this. I looked at some stack overflow questions for setting multiple alarms. But here how do I do it? Should I just read the whole weeks database entries i.e 5 times/day for 7 days..And set around 35 alarms together? Or should I just set one alarm at a time. And when that alarm is fired just read the next entry from the Database and schedule an alarm for that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a service which will pick up the 5 values from the database everyday at a particular time.

Then add multiple entries in the AlarmManger with different unique ID.

**Adding alarm at particular time:**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

//9 AM 
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, YourClass.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

**Setting Multiple alarm:**

```
AlarmManager[] alarmManager=new AlarmManager[24];
intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
for(f=0;f<arr2.length;f++){
   Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmR.this, Riciving.class);
   pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmR.this, f,intent, 0);

   alarmManager[f] = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager[f].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,arr2[f] ,pi);

   intentArray.add(pi);

}
```

Hope this should work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. What if I want to cancel and reschedule? For eg. the user can change a setting due to which the 5 times per day would be changed.

Comment: You can add settings or edit settings for service. To change or reschedule it just edit it .and start it again. It will work. Some of the applications "auto sms" google play store use the same concept. Try doing that way.

Comment: @John what do you have in arr2 ? actually i do need to implement this.